# GNS 430 Instrument Panel Self Test Page OBS readout does not agree with OBS Hdg selected on CDI

Tags: navigation, configuration, gns430

Our Newly installed Overhauled GNS 430 OBS readout on the Instrument Panel Self Test Page does not agree with the Heading selected on our CDI.  Prior to the 430 overhaul they agreed perfectly. Difference is 5 degrees.  Is this a configuration setup issue on the 430?

Note: There is a configuration page in the installation manual which describes a OBS calibration  "This page allows the user to verify the CDI outputs from the VOR/LOC/GS receiver as well as the OBS resolver input to the VOR receiver" but im hesitant to start poking around in config without confirmation.

Comment: Have you checked with the company who did the overhaul or researched the GNS 430's user's manual?

Comment: There is nothing specific in the Users manual about a what Ill call a "split" indication on the Self Test page other that the OBS selected Heading and the self test readout on the Garmin should match wihtin 2 degrees or so, I think the Garmin readout confirms that the OBS heading input to the VOR receiver is working.   Garmin did the overhaul , getting an answer from them is challenging. But No I haven't checked with them,,,yet. But now that you mentioned it I will call the Avionics shop on Monday, Thanks.